# Microsoft Word - Table of figures contains copies of figures instead of only the figure captions

Tags: microsoft-word, charts, table-of-contents

I have inserted captions in the maps of my document and I have created a table of figures. When I updated the table of figures, some figures are shown in it. Despite the fact that I deleted them from the table of figures, they showed again in the next update. What is the problem?

[image: image table of figures]

Comment: It looks like you have an image as part of your cross-references, which is why it is appearing in your table.
Just make sure that there is a line break between the image and the caption for that image, that should take the image out of the table.
HTH

Comment: Great, if you could accept my answer as completed, it'd be most appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have an image as part of your cross-references, which is why it is appearing in your table. Just make sure that there is a line break between the image and the caption for that image, that should take the image out of the table. HTH